# .NET 6 WinUI 3 Community Toolkit Datagrid Checkbox Causes Crashing

Tags: c#, xaml, datagrid, .net-6.0, winui-3

I have a content dialog in a page that is called from a button, and I've noticed some odd crashing behavior when I added a `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` to it. If I add one `DataGridCheckBoxColumn`, the application will crash on the line `ContentDialogResult result = await assignUsersContentDialog.ShowAsync();` called from the button (see below) during the fourth time in a row I open the content dialog.

However, if I add two `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` and open the content dialog twice in a row, it will crash. If I take away EITHER the binding or the `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` from the data grid, it will no longer crash. I suspect this might be because there is a problem with the Microsoft's `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` and in either case the check boxes will not be displayed.

But maybe my code is causing the crash somehow. I looked it over and over and can't find the culprit, but maybe you can?

XAML as part of a page:

```
<ContentDialog x:Name="ContentDialogTest" Width="1100"
   PrimaryButtonText="Accept" IsPrimaryButtonEnabled="True" PrimaryButtonClick="assignUsersContentDialog_PrimaryButtonClick"
   CloseButtonText="Cancel" >
    <StackPanel>
        <controls:DataGrid x:Name="dataGridTest" 
                Margin="12" GridLinesVisibility="All" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="PowderBlue" VerticalGridLinesBrush="PowderBlue"
                BorderBrush="PowderBlue" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.AssignUsersGrid, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
                <controls:DataGridCheckBoxColumn IsReadOnly="True" 
                    Header="Add User" 
                    Width="75" />
                <controls:DataGridCheckBoxColumn IsReadOnly="True" 
                    Header="Add User 2" 
                    Width="75" />
                <!--a couple of DataGridTextColumns not shown-->
            </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
        </controls:DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</ContentDialog>
```

Button event for showing the ContentDialog:

```
    private async void AddEditAssignUsers_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewModel.SetAssignUsersGrid();

        ContentDialogResult result = await assignUsersContentDialog.ShowAsync();           
    }
```

Code for setting up the oservable collection bound to the data grid:

```
private void SetAssignUsersGrid()
{
        //Limit Global ProjectDbUser list to those from the current project
        IEnumerable<ProjectDbuser> projUsers = _UnitOfWorkDbGlobal.ProjectDbUsers.GetAllUsersFromProject(SelectedDataGrProj.ProjectDbguid);

        //limit UserAd to users not currenlty in the project
        IEnumerable<UserAd> userAds = _UnitOfWorkDbGlobal.UserAds.GetAll().Where(ad => !projUsers.Any(p => ad.UserAdguid == p.UserAdguid)).OrderBy(x => x.UserAddisplayName).ToList();

        List<TempUser> assign = new List<TempUser>();
        foreach (UserAd ua in userAds)
        {
            TempUser tu = new TempUser().Clean();
            tu.Selected = false;
            tu.UserAdguid = ua.UserAdguid;
            tu.UserAddisplayName = ua.UserAddisplayName;
            tu.UserAdfirstName = ua.UserAdfirstName;
            tu.UserAdmiddleInitial = ua.UserAdmiddleInitial;
            tu.UserAdlastName = ua.UserAdlastName;
            assign.Add(tu);
        }

        AssignUsersGrid = new ObservableCollection<TempUser>(assign);
}
```

Comment: Can you make sure this is reproducible code for your problem? I created a test app by pasting your code and filling some gaps but no crash.

Comment: Thanks for giving it a try. The code is from the app I'm running. I'm not sure what other code would be needed to reproduce this, honestly. Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: No clue. Have you tried the same ``DataGrid`` code outside the ``ContentDialog``?

Comment: I have not tried the exact same code, but the problem seems tied to the `ShowAsync()` method for the `ContentDialog`.

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding For me it crashed after I repeatedly opened and closed the `ContentDialog` It would crash after four opens if I had one checkbox and after two opens if I had two checkboxes. Did you try reopening it multiple times in a row?

Comment: Yes, I tried open/close several times but no crash. I guess the problem is in the data bound to the ``DataGridCheckBoxColumn``.

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding As you can see from my example above, there is no data bound to the check box. I did have data bound to it, but even when I removed the binding, the problem persisted.

Comment: Can you create a minimal reproducible project and share it on GitHub?

Comment: I'll give it a try. I'll follow up.